# ACL express.js allow role access to subpaths

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js, express, acl

I'm using following implementation of ACL for my express.js application: https://www.npmjs.com/package/acl

Is there any way to give access to given role for all subpaths of specified path?

```
    acl.allow([{
        roles: ['admin'],
        allows: [
            { resources: '/admin/*', permissions: '*' },
        ]
    }
]);
```

is not working for me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works like this:

```
acl.allow([{
  roles  : ['admin'],
  allows : [
    { resources: '/admin', permissions: '*' },
  ]
}]);
```

Combined with having the middleware only look at the first part of the URL:

```
app.use('/admin', acl.middleware(1), ... });
```

This basically implements a check that would allow the role `admin` to access any URL that is prefixed by `/admin`

Comment: I am not using middleware, rather isAllowed function, but now knowing that, there is no regex in resource, I will just cut my req url, thanks

Comment: If you're using `app.use('/admin', ...)`, you can also use [`req.baseUrl`](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#req.baseUrl) which would be `/admin`.